# Restricting IdentityServer3 ClientCredentials access by IP address

Tags: oauth, identityserver3

I'm implementing an identity server using IdentityServer3, and want to restrict a particular ClientCredentials client to a set of IP addresses.

I've tried a few things:

- I see an AllowedCorsOrigins property on the Client object, and if I enable this I see IdentityServer logging warnings, but it doesn't prevent access.
- Injected OwinEnvironmentService into my UserService's constructor - UserService doesn't seem to be used by the ClientCredentials flow.

Is this possible, or am I misunderstanding how to use ClientCredentials?

Answer (score 0):

This is not easily possible with the client credentials flow. But you could implement a customized m grant type instead.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customGrantTypes.html